# Accidentally speak Japanese on reflex

Tags: psycholinguistics, japanese

There is one time I woke up late and accidentally speak in Japanese "yabai" which means "oh no" or "this is bad", when I came around after finishing getting ready I then realized I've just spoken in Japanese. And also there is one time something sticks on my foot and in my desperate attempt to shake it off my feet I repeatedly says "bikurista" which means "that surprised me" which then again I realized I've just spoken in Japanese without noticing it..

What does it means and why does it happen?

For your information I really like Japan and been studying their language by myself through apps, anime, and drama.

Comment: I think it's pretty normal to use some words from another language when you are in emotions. I think it happens becouse you are into Japanese like you said and you start thinking in this language which comes with pleasure from speaking it.

I can relate to that that I used to use English words for some occassions rather then my native tongue.

Anyway, I am not sure if this question belongs here to this site?

Comment: @ShaqI don't even know where to ask about this. I've tried stack exchange for Japanese language and the reject my question and led me here. Do you have any suggestion where should I ask?

Comment: You can leave it here for now. It might be the best place actaully... Anyway I shared what I think. And I am happy to welcome you to stackexchange!

Comment: I think you may have answered your own question. *Q: What does it mean and why does it happen? A: [You] really like Japan and been studying their language*. It's no different than if you really liked piano and had been studying Mozart, and you found yourself humming bits of Mozart melodies.